# sqlalchemy inheritance, how to update polymorphic identity to default when changing attribute

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

So I have the following models:

```
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, Integer, create_engine, ForeignKey, Boolean, Text
from datetime import datetime
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy.orm.scoping import scoped_session
from sqlalchemy.orm.session import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import event

Base = declarative_base()


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    type = Column(String(50), default = "user")
    email = Column(String(64), unique=True, index=True)
    username = Column(String(64), unique=True, index=True)
    role_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('roles.id'))
    __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_on": type, "polymorphic_identity": "user"}
    
class Role(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'roles'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(64), unique=True)
    default = Column(Boolean, default = False, index = True)
    permissions = Column(Integer)
    users: sqlalchemy.orm.Query = relationship('User', backref='role', lazy="dynamic")

class AdminUser(User):
    role = Role(name="Administrator")
    __mapper_args__ = {
        "polymorphic_identity": "AdministratorUser",
    }

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///')
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(engine))
```

If I create an instance of an AdminUser:

```
user1 = AdminUser(email="admin@test.edu", username="test1")
session.add(user1)
session.commit()
```

Then `administrator.role.name` is indeed `Administrator`.

But if I want to change the role of user1 to some other role like this:

```
user1.role = Role(name = "someOtherRole")
session.add(user1)
session.commit()
```

It doesn't work, `user1.role.name` is still `Administrator`.

Using `update` like this also did not work
`session.query(AdminUser).filter_by(username = user1.username).update(dict(role = Role(name="someOtherRole")))`

It threw an exception

`"Role" object has no attribute '_bulk_update_tuples'`

I realize this is because the `type` of user1 is still `AdministratorUser`. Is there a way to automatically update the `type` to that of the base class (i.e. `user`) if I change the role?